# Program crash after setting QApplication::style twice

Tags: c++, qt, crash, segmentation-fault, qmake

```
#include <QApplication>
int main() {
   QApplication::setStyle("windows");
   QApplication::setStyle("windows");
}
```

This program produces `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. My `qmake` version is `4.7.2`. Is this a Qt bug or my version is too old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create an instance of QApplication before you set it's style. From the documentation

> Ownership of the style object is transferred to QApplication, so
>   QApplication will delete the style object on application exit or when
>   a new style is set and the old style is still the parent of the
>   application object.

I'm assuming it's crashing because there is no QApplication to take ownership of the style. In general, creating the QApplication is one of the first things you should do.

```
#include <QApplication>
int main() {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QApplication::setStyle("windows");
   QApplication::setStyle("windows");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, why the function is static if it requires an object?

Comment: I don't know the history of Qt, but I assume they are static so that you can access the QApplication from anywhere. QApplication has a static self variable that is set by the constructor, so that static functions get access to the application instance. Any static functions called before the constructor get a NULL pointer. Not the best design, but I'm sure there was a reason at the time. It would be clearer if you had to call QApplication::instance()->setStyle() or something like that.